# jQuery validation - only show one error message

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

Is there a way to only show the latest error-message thrown, when using the validation-plugin for jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should look into the `groups` and `errorPlacement` options to the `validate` method. That should work out for you.

[jQuery Validation validate( [options] )](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions)