# jQuery validation - only show error message of last field validated

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

How do I prevent that multiple error messages are shown when I submit a form?

I would like to display only the error message of last field validated: `password`. I've tried to use `errorPlacement` as suggested in a different post: [jQuery validation - only show one error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816702/jquery-validation-only-show-one-error-message) and `$('.alert').remove();` without success.

What I've got so far:

```
<script>
    let form = $('#login');

    $('#login').validate({
        onkeyup: false,
        onclick: false,
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error) {
            $('.alert').remove();

            let div = $(
                '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">\n' +
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>\n' +
                '<h4><i class="icon fa fa-warning"></i>Opgepast!</h4>\n' +
                '<p>' + error.text() + '</p>\n' +
                '</div>'
            );

            div.insertBefore(form);
        },
        messages: {
            username: {
                required: "Gelieve een gebruikersnaam in te vullen."
            },
            password: {
                required: "Gelieve een wachtwoord in te vullen."
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: When you click the submit button the two error messages are show one after another. The password message comes second so it's the one displayed after the form is submitted. That said I personally cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yes correct, after submit, the required error message is shown. However, when I click on `username` field to enter a value, it seems that `onclick: false` doesn't work anymore, since it immediately shows the error message applicable to that field. Did I configured something wrong?

Comment: Basically, I only want the validation to be done when I press the submit button and if there are error messages, that only the last one is shown.

Comment: Show enough code to reproduce the issue.  Where is the HTML markup of your form?

Comment: I think you may want to go back and [read the documentation again](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate).  If you want the messages to display outside of the form, you would not use `errorPlacement` - that's for custom placement within the form such as before or after an input.  Have a look at `showErrors`, as well as the other options for handling messages and message lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `errorPlacement` to `showErrors` as suggested by @Sparky. Result:

```
showErrors: function(object) {
    $('.alert').remove();

    let amount = Object.keys(object).length;

    if(amount > 0){
        let key = Object.keys(object)[0];
        let value = object[key];

        let div = $(
          '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">\n' +
          '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>\n' + 
          '<h4><i class="icon fa fa-warning"></i>Opgepast!</h4>\n' +
          '<p>' + value + '</p></div>');

        div.insertBefore(form);
    }
```

Comment: That simply [disables the `focusout` validation trigger when leaving a field](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onfocusout).  Seems like a bit of a hack considering the problem you describe:  *"I would like to display only the error message of last field validated"* - What about when initially filling out the form?  You've already disabled `onkeyup` and `onclick` so you've basically now disabled all interactive validation just to stop the next message from appearing.  The best way to solve this is to properly use the callback functions; such as `showErrors` instead of `errorPlacement`.